# Inconsistent Topology Problem

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, workflow

I have a pretty consistent problem every time I model a character and I feel like its largely to do with the topology.

[image]

The amount of faces is different on the other side which gives me the impression that if I were to extrude the legs then the number of faces would be uneven for the two sides.

Are there any tips on topology for future reference? I've been a blender user for years but I could never find the modelling technique that suits me best - I tried modelling from a cube but that only meant I'm restricted to the amount of faces that I subdivided it with.

I also attempted to model using a reference and using planes to surround the drawing, which gave me this weird problem. The faces get really small behind the head so when I model the torso the faces get even smaller.

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I can't figure out what picture 1 shows. I see that the left marked area has fewer edge loops than the right marked area. What does "The amount of faces is different on the other side" mean? Which side? Left <=> right? Front <=> back? You're using a mirror modifier. Shouldn't the extruded legs have then the same number of faces?

Comment: I didn't really explain it well, yeah I used the mirror modifier but I only made it go to one axis since I was making the face. (by other side i was referring to the front and back, haha)